# Is there any online tool or any other way to set a certain string compatible to java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am not very experienced programer and am working on strings. I am facing a problem of setting each and every double quotation marks by entering '\' before it (to make it compatible for java compiler). For example:

I am using GSON library to get strings like below:

```
String example = "[{"salesChannelId":1,"
            + ""companyName":"Prüftechnik Condition Monitoring","
            + ""country":"DE","
            + ""isActive":true,"
            + ""salesChannelContact":[{"salesChannelContactId":40,"
            + ""name":"Hans Muller","
            + ""isActive":true},"
            + "{"salesChannelContactId":41,"
            + ""name":"Peter Pan","
            + ""isActive":true},"}]";
```

and I convert every such string to equaivalent backslashed string:

```
String example = "[{\"salesChannelId\":1,"
            + "\"companyName\":\"Prüftechnik Condition Monitoring\","
            + "\"country\":\"DE\","
            + "\"isActive\":true,"
            + "\"salesChannelContact\":[{\"salesChannelContactId\":40,"
            + "\"name\":\"Hans Muller\","
            + "\"isActive\":true},"
            + "{\"salesChannelContactId\":41,"
            + "\"name\":\"Peter Pan\","
            + "\"isActive\":true},\"}]";
```

Now the problem is that I have allot of strings and very lengthy too, and I don't want to waste my time in parsing them or writing a separate code for them. Is there any online tool or any shortcut to get rid of it?

Comment: why not write simple method to do it for You?

Comment: it looks like you are creating json, use gson or jackson

Comment: @NimChimpsky , Yes but not related to current question, I want to replace " with \" everywhere in the string at the moment. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: It is, on the opposite, quite related to the question. You suffer the XY problem syndrome. This is JSON, use a JSON library!

Comment: @fge , plz see my question edited!

Comment: I think this is an editor task. Use an editor.

Comment: If you want to escape `Strings` automatically in **Eclipse**, you can fix your problem by switching an option: **Window => Preferences => Java => Editor => Typing => Escape text when pasting into a string literal**. This will do the trick! In **JDeveloper** for example it will do it automatically when you paste a `String` into the quotes `"{paste here}"`.

Comment: @ bobbel , yes exactly this I wanted, thank you very much! ...I don't know why people voted my question negative though I clearly explained my problem, it is really unmotivated for a new joiner like me!

Comment: Well... you've never talked about **pasting** a string in your IDE! It was all about how to "parse" your `String` to an escaped `String`. That's probably why you didn't get so much acceptance to your question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Gson, use Gson:

```
new JsonPrimitive(theOriginalJsonAsString).toString()
```

This will create a JSON String.

Comment: I am getting my string from gson.toJson(Object) method, I am already using it but I want " parsed to \" automatically, this what I asked!
Thanks for your time!

Comment: An XY problem then. You should have mentioned in the qestion that you already used Gson. Gson _can_ build JSON texts the way Jackson does, just use the equivalents but DON'T use strings...

Comment: No, I don't have format problem, GSON is working perfect and I am getting a valid string too, I want a string which have \" instead of " everywhere in it!

Comment: Why?? This makes no sense at all whatsoever. Why do you want such a string?

Comment: Anyway, see edit. But I persist, this is an XY problem. If you mentioned your original problem to start with, I am sure a better solution could be found

Comment: @ fge , I don't understand why its difficult to get my question though I think I have explained my problem well..., bobbel answered it above..., thanks for your time mate!